# How to fire a custom validator in client side at ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my custom validator class:

```
public class PriceAttribute : ValidationAttribute {

    public double MinPrice { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }
        var price = (double)value;
        if (price < MinPrice) {
            return false;
        }
        double cents = price - Math.Truncate(price);
        if (cents < 0.99 || cents >= 0.995) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And my Model:

```
public class MyModel {

    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Price(MinPrice = 1.2, ErrorMessage = "hmm not good value")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

But this validator fires with postback. How can I implement it to fire client side like the `[Required]` validator. Is there any jQuery reference to add in the view page? Or do I need a custom script to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomClientSideValidatio.aspx) describes in detail, which steps you have to do in order to also get client side validation.

> but this validator fire with postback

Please note there is no postback, just plain HTTP POSTs in MVC.

Comment: I think people have used the term "postback" to refer to self-posting pages before WebForms, though WebForms did sort of take over the term. Many asp.net mvc sites end up technically doing "post backs" by posting a form to the same url from which it was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You better use the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) validation engine.